# Working with kotlin/compose compared to java

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

With java, we have fragments for every screen with its own logic/design. Here i have one activity, and should put all the app logic there?
I dont see that working for larger projects at all. Im so confused how to start the project and structurize it. Where does all the app logic go?

I just need some guidance, thanks in advance!

*EDIT: I've been missing the whole ViewModel stuff, guess I shouldn't have rushed into development, and should have spent more time reading the documentation :)

Comment: For your own sake - never put any logic in neither Fragment nor Activity! Those should be limited to putting up views in response to the system. Android is insidious, as it tempts you into cramming everything into one god-object. Every architecture's main purpose is to distance you from the Fragment/Activity as much as feasible. Once you have a good architecture, swapping Activity for Compose is trivial.

Comment: Do you know where I can find a well written project to use as a guideline? Because, for legacy projects, we put screen logic/requests in fragments. Don't know what alternative there is. With kotlin/compose, equivalent is ViewModels

Comment: For me, the key was to stop thinking that "Application is UI, UI has logic". No, logic is the application. It may have UI. Or command line. Or something else. Everything that's system related: `android.app.Application` , `Activity`, etc is subservient to your application. Design your app with a goal that in some distant future you could remove UI module and replace it with command line, or voice command, or VR or whatever. Or compile as Kotlin Multiplaform and run on iOS. ViewModel is also part of UI layer, it merely models UI. Look up "onion architecture", that's a start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scope of your question is rather broad.

In terms of project structure, Compose doesn't have to be vastly different from the activity/fragment approach. You could consider a composable comparable to a fragment (or an activity in some cases). For example, you might have had `LoginFragment` before and now you'll have a composable called `LoginScreen`.

You can use the the same architectural and design patterns, e.g. you can use MVVM with both approaches, but the implementation differs a little.

You can organise the application layers in the same way, e.g. UI/domain/data, Compose is simply an alternate UI layer.

For the automatic locking, again it's not really any different, you need to observe the correct lifecycle events, e.g. `onStop`, and then have some logic to lock the application, e.g. this might call a method on a view model that changes some state to "locked".

Definitely don't try to put all your application logic in one activity. In fact, you probably shouldn't be putting any logic inside your activity with Compose. Consider it more of container for your Compose application.

Many Compose apps may be as simple as this from the activity perspective:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        setContent {
            MyApp() // <-- A composable function
        }
    }
}
```

It's probably worth investing some time looking at [the getting started guide for Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/documentation) and it should hopefully clear things up for you and point you in the right direction.

Comment: Hm, that's very interesting. If they just call a composable function, where do they put all the application logic? I see that from composables, you can't execute any other additional background logic/start requests etc

Comment: Compose is just for UI. Take a look at the view model docs - https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel and this might also be useful - https://developer.android.com/courses/android-basics-compose/course